# SQLAlchemy: session.close() or session.commit()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am newbie to SQLAlchemy. And now I need to query some data, as follows

```
def get_xx():
    sess = Session()
    return sess.query(xx).filter(
        xx.id == 3, xx.status == 1
    ).first()
```

The isolation level is `repeatable read` and autocommit is off; So I always get the same result even the value has been updated.

And now, the question occur, sess.close() and sess.commit(), which method should I use?

The final solution I attempt to use as follows, however I am not sure if it is good enough (close after commit)?

```
@contextmanager
def auto_session():
    sess = Session()
    try:
        yield sess
        sess.commit()
    except:  # swallow any exception
        sess.rollback()
    finally:
        sess.close()
```

And the source code changed

```
def get_xx():
    with auto_session() as sess:
        return sess.query(xx).filter(
            xx.id == 3, xx.status == 1
        ).first()
```

Comment: Read ["Committing"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#committing) and ["Closing"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#closing) and the linked method documentations.

Comment: What I want is only getting refresh value, commit() is enough here. So close() is not necessary, right?

Comment: In that case commit or rollback is enough. The session will start a new implicit transaction that sees data committed before it.

Comment: Committing will also just expire the state of all instances in the session so that they receive fresh state on next access. Closing expunges (removes) all instances from the session.

Answer (score 0):

Your session commit and close is absolutely right what you have done. And in your source code you can try this..

```
from operator import and_
def get_xx():
    with auto_session() as sess:
        return sess.query(xx).filter(and_(
            xx.id == 3, xx.status == 1
        )).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

after commit you can refresh the session and then close the session.

```
@contextmanager
def auto_session():
    sess = Session()
    try:
        yield sess
        sess.commit()
        sess.refresh()
    except:  # swallow any exception
        sess.rollback()
    finally:
        sess.close()



from operator import and_
def get_xx():
    with auto_session() as sess:
        return sess.query(xx).filter(and_(
            xx.id == 3, xx.status == 1
        )).first()
```

Comment: Isn't it quite pointless to issue a refresh immediately followed by a close? Former would fetch fresh state for instances found in session, latter would then remove all those instances from the session. Not to mention that [`Session.refresh()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.refresh) requires 1 positional argument: the instance to refresh, as it operates on instance basis.